# WinHttpException when calling a web service

Tags: web-services, wcf, .net-core, windows-10

I'm trying to call any WCF service in code locally which gives me the following exception:
`WinHttpException: The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation`.

Some code example: `await service.ReadMultipleAsync(filters.ToArray(), null, 1);`. This might not say anything though. The weird thing is that it worked before updating windows 10. This might be a coincidence, but I have absolutely no code changes.

I can also talk directly to the WFC service through some tooling, so it cannot be some sort of IP blocking or firewall. But doing this through code results in the error, both using Kerstel or IIS Express.

Possible relevant packages:

- .Net core - 2.2
- System.ServiceModel.... - 4.4.0

I'm currently clueless. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:

A more detailed exception:

```
System.Net.Http.WinHttpException (8007139F, 5023): The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation
   at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.StartRequest(WinHttpRequestState state)
```

Comment: Namely, there is something wrong with your client side. Have you updated the service reference after you have updated your OS, provided that you call the service by adding service reference?

Answer (score 1):

I did a rollback from windows 10 version 1903 to 1803 and it suddenly started working again. Not really a solution but it works. Still no clue on what's wrong. Might be a bug?

Comment: which way did you use on the client side to call the service, client proxy class or ChannelFactory? I think there might need some runtime support(some Dll library). the best way is that update your client and call the service again).

Comment: Had the same problem also with version 1903. Rolling back indeed did solve the problem. Tried regenerating the proxy classes numerous times which did not result in any code changes. Glad to find this post